Is the converse of the Tube Lemma true? If $\pi\colon X\times Z \to Z$ is always closed, is $X$ compact?
One of the forms of the Tube Lemma is the following: if $X$ is compact, then for every topological space $Z$, the projection mapping $\pi_Z: X\times Z \to Z$ is closed.
In various algebraic geometry textbooks, to motivate the "appropriate" notion of compactness for schemes, it's claimed that the converse is also true: if $\pi_Z:X\times Z \to Z$ is closed for every $Z$, then $X$ is compact; i.e., a converse to the Tube lemma. How does one prove this fact?

There’s a proof in the question here.

The straightforward way to approach this is using filters/nets or the Stone-Čech compactification. But there are more elementary approaches.
One way to prove this is in ncatlab, and I created this question to make it more accessible in the internet, since it's quite obscure and took a bit of research to find it. I'll walk through this proof in my own words.
Since $\pi_Z$ is closed, the strategy is to use the characterization of compactness in terms of closed sets through the finite intersection property. From a collection of F.I.P-closed sets, one builds a space $\tilde{X}$, using a construction which resembles the Alexandroff compactification, but is actually very different and uses the discretization of $X.^{[1]}$ The important part is that the new open sets introduced in this $\tilde X$ are neighborhoods of infinity $(\infty)$ built from $\mathcal C$, and $X$ is dense in $\tilde{X}$. I'll proceed with the proof.

Let $X$ be a topological space, and suppose that $\pi\colon X\times Z \to Z$ is closed for every topological space $Z$. We have to show that every family $\mathcal C$ of closed sets satisfying the F.I.P has nonempty intersection. Let $\mathcal C = \{F_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a collection of closed sets in $X$ satisfying the F.I.P.
Take $X$ as a set and let $X_d$ be the discrete topological space associated to $X$. We set $\tilde X = \tilde X_{\mathcal C} =  X\sqcup \{\infty\}$, and its topology is generated by the subbasis of sets of the form $U \subseteq X_d$, or $F_i\ \cup \{\infty\}$. The mapping
$$\begin{align*}X_d &\to \tilde{X} \\ x &\mapsto x\end{align*}$$
is clearly continuous ($X_d$ is discrete) and open (by the first part of the definition of the subbasis). So $\tilde{X}$ is an extension of $X_d$.
We'll need a lemma: I claim that $\{\infty\}$ is not open. In fact, if $\{\infty\}$ was open, the finite intersections of the subbase are a base for $\tilde X$, so $\{\infty\}$ is actually a basic open. If $\{\infty\} = \bigcap U_i$ with some $U_j \subseteq X_d$, then clearly $\{\infty\} \subseteq U_j \implies \infty \in U_j \subseteq X$, which is false since we took the disjoint union for this construction. So $\{\infty\} = \bigcap (F_i \cup \{\infty\}) = (\bigcap F_i) \cup \{\infty\}$, but this means that $\bigcap F_i = \emptyset$ which is also false, given that the $F_i$ satisfy the finite intersection property. In particular, $X$ is dense in $\tilde X$, since $\overline{X} \supseteq X$, so it's either $X$ or $\tilde{X} = X \cup \{\infty\}$. In the first case, $X$ is closed, so $\tilde X\setminus X = \{\infty\}$ is open, which is false, so the latter must happen.
Take $\Delta = \{(x,x): x \in X\} \subseteq X\times \tilde X$ the diagonal ($X$ with its original topology), and $K:= \overline{\Delta}$ the closure in the product space. Since $K$ is closed and $\pi\colon X\times \tilde X \to \tilde X$ is closed, $\pi(K)$ is closed. Then $\infty \in \pi(K)$: in fact, $\pi(K) \supseteq \pi(\Delta) = X$, so $\pi(K) \supseteq \overline X = \tilde{X}$. This means that $\exists (x, \infty) \in K$. We'll prove that this $x$ lies in the intersection of all $\mathcal C$.
Since $K = \overline{\Delta}$, this means that every (in particular, basic) open neighborhood of $(x,\infty) \in X\times \tilde X$ intersects $\Delta$. If $x \not \in \bigcap_{i\in I} F_i$, there's some $F_j$ s.t. $x \not \in F_j$. So $F_j^C$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, and $\infty \in F_j\cup \{\infty\}$, so $$(F_j^C\times (F_j\cup\{\infty\})) \cap \Delta \ne \emptyset.$$ But this "$\cap \Delta \ne 0$" condition is the same as requiring that both sets have nonempty intersection in $X$; i.e., $F_j^C \cap F_j \ne \emptyset$, which is clearly false. Therefore $x \in \bigcap\limits_{i\in i} F_i$, and the claim is proved. $\blacksquare$

[1]: I'm not really sure if this is necessary! $\tilde X$ is built from a subbasis, but decreeing that the "usual" opens of $\tilde X$ are those from $X$ seems to do the trick. An effort to adapt this proof to avoid using $X_d$ is appreciated. Maybe the reason of $\tilde{X}$ being build from the discretization has some inspiration from Stone-Čech, but I really don't know.
Remark: $\tilde{X}$ needs not to be compact and usually never is, unlike Alexandroff's. For example: take $X = \mathbb Z\setminus\{-1,1\}$ with the discrete topology, and the family $\mathcal C = \{F_i\}_{i \ge 1}$, where $F_i := \langle p_i \rangle$, the ideals generated by the $i$-th prime. They satisfy the F.I.P., and  $(\bigcup\limits_{n=2}^\infty F_n)\cup (F_1\cup \{\infty\}) = \tilde X_\mathcal{C}$ but this has no finite subcover (removing any of these sets misses some prime $p_k$).
In general, given $x \in X$, $\{x\}$ is open in $\tilde{X}$, and if $X$ has any finite closed subset $F$ (e.g. $X$ is $T_1$), $\{F\}$ has the F.I.P., so $(\bigcup \limits_{x\in X} \{x\}) \cup (F\cup\{\infty\}$ covers $\tilde X\supseteq X$. So this has a finite subcover $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^N\{x_n\}\cup\{\infty\}$ which covers $X$, so $X$ must finite. (The same argument holds if one the finite intersections in $\mathcal C$ is a finite set). Maybe avoiding $X_d$ actually gives a compact space in some cases with some neat interpretation.
